# How to solve a problem with creating files by program after make py2exe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I made a small program to login and register.
After that I try to export it to .exe, but program have a problem with creating files.

The method which i use to create a file

> ```
>         path = "hasla" + '\\' + Login + ".txt"
> ```

```
                result = hashlib.md5(password.encode())
                f = open (path, "w")
                f.write(result.hexdigest())
                f.closed
```

And screenshot from cmd:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZAkM.png)

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
  File "Logowanie2.py", line 69, in <module>
  File "Logowanie2.py", line 14, in Register
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hasla\\123.txt'
[13900] Failed to execute script logowanie2
```

Thank you in advance

14 line:                     f = open (sciezka, "w")
69 line:             Register(Sciezka_pl)

Comment: Show output as properly formatted text in the question, not as image.

Comment: Ok, I've made it.

Comment: The path is relative to the current working directory. There must be a folder `"hasla"` already present in the same directory from which the EXE was started (usually the directory in which EXE is located). Relative paths are generally a bad idea.

Comment: So it's better to make a solid path to a folder which will be create ?

Comment: An absolute path is usually better. Folders are not created automatically by `open` but there are `os.mkdir` and `os.makedirs` for that.